# I can't paint the object rightly in my 3D window, and it doesn't show any unwrapped mesh in left windows

Tags: texture-painting

In texture painting, I can't use draw tool to paint my object in 3D window.

First, I use a circle to build a object. Everything is all good at the beginning.

Finally I started to give it a texture painting. I creat a new material and save it, I can draw in left 2D window, but it doesn't reflect on my 3D object. If I use paint tool to draw colors on my 3D object in the right 3D window, it would not work normally, it would paint the whole object just like the fill tool, and the color is gray, is not like the color I choose.

I check where is the problem, I found in UV editing surface, there is no unwrapped mesh in the left window, I am wondering if this is the reason why I can't paint.

Then I choose the object, Press U to unwrap it, it seems nothing be changed.

Then I try to use another file to do the same painting, and it works, but in my circle object, it just can't be paint rightly.

[image]
[image]

Comment: you need to unwrap, and you also need to plug the Image Texture (with the image you've created) into the Principled BSDF node (or Diffuse node), otherwise it won't display

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me! I would try your method! Good day!

Comment: If it still doesn't work, please share your file (with the image packed within): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thank you very much!! I finally figure it out!! I am trying to mark seam my edges, and it works! I can unwrap my object, and it can paint freely, oh!  It confuse me two days already~finally I can go to the next step!

Comment: if you only plan to paint in the 3D view you don't need to mark seam, you can just unwrap with the Smart UV Project mode